# OData web api in a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, odata

I have a curious problem. I want to host a web api in a windows service. The controller I want to use should be of type ODataController (System.Web.OData), like this:

```
using System.Web.OData;

/// <summary>
/// The controller.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="System.Web.OData.ODataController" />
public class MyController : ODataController
{ ... }
```

So far, so good, when the windows service project runs as a console application it works fine, I can call all my routes with fiddler and everything is ok. When I try to install the windows service (as a windows application) with installutil the installation fails with the message that "at least one type in the assembly cannot be loaded". When my controller is of type ApiController the installation works fine. I also tried to add a try-catch-block in my project installer, which sould catch the ReflectionTypeLoadException so I can access the LoaderExceptions, but there is no output.

Is System.Web.OData missing some references and how can I find out which one?
Does anybody here have a suggestion what can I do?